# How to create an Google Currents like layout

Tags: android, layout, webview, multiple-columns

Does anybody know how the article layout in the Google Currents Android app is built? I'd like to use some very similar layout for my app.

Example:

[image: Example]

The first thing which came to my mind was to build up an the layout with a WebView with multicolumn stlye (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/). Am I on the right way or is my suspicion completely wrong.
How do I get the page flip through the swipe/fling gesture and how to get the corresponding page indicator at the bottom?

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: You can decompile the apk and look at all the xml files.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/android-getting-source-code-from-an-apk-file

Answer (score 1):

You must use native views android and not webView because it is not efficient. But if you begun on Android you can actually use a webView is a good learning.

However, if you're interreses the layout android [http://developer.android.com/](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) the website is a very good teaching technique. And what is the view of pourfaire text scroll from right to left, I encourage you to use the library [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/).

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hint with the ViewPagerIndicator! This sounds really helpful. What do you mean with using native WebViews?

Comment: No problem. I'm also no natively english speaking person. - Native Android Views would also be great. The point is, that I want mixture of text and pictures in two one or two columns (depending on the screen width). If the text is longer than one page the text should be continued on the next page, which should be reached with a swipe gesture.

Comment: You can realize what the html and css directly in Android layouts. This is probably the case that Google Current!

Comment: OK! How do I get a multicolumn TextView or how do I determine where the text shall be splitted (for the next column or the next page)?

Comment: To optimize the space to suit your screen you can use the weight, and the text of diffilement can use ScrollView.

Comment: To determine the position of these different views, you can use gravity.

Comment: I don't want to sroll vertically. I want that the first column is filled with text and if this column is full the remaining text shall be filled into the second column. If this is full the remaining text shall be filled in the first column of the next page,.....

Comment: Okay, I just understand, this is actually complex I've never encountered this type of problem...